# How do you get Ubuntu to automatically run a program every time the screen is unlocked?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script

I have a script I would like to have automatically invoked every time the screen is unlocked. Does Ubuntu provide some support for users who wish to do this?

Comment: I am not aware of anything.  I suspect you would have to some hacking/patching of your favorite screen saver application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible, albeit a bit tricky. [GnomeScreensaver documentation](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) states:

> **Is there a way to perform actions when the screensaver activates or deactivates? Or when the session becomes idle?**
>
> One way is to watch for the D-Bus signals from gnome-screensaver. Here's an example of how to perform actions when the session becomes idle or is no longer idle using the Perl language:

```
my $cmd = "dbus-monitor --session \"type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member='SessionIdleChanged'\"";

open (IN, "$cmd |");

while (<IN>) {
    if (m/^\s+boolean true/) {
        print "*** Session is idle ***\n";
    } elsif (m/^\s+boolean false/) {
        print "*** Session is no longer idle ***\n";
    }
}
```

Although when I examined using `dbus-monitor` and proceeded to lock/unlock the screen the signal emitted was

```
path=/org/gnome/ScreenSaver; interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver; member=ActiveChanged
boolean true
```

when screen was locked and

```
path=/org/gnome/ScreenSaver; interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver; member=ActiveChanged
boolean false
```

When unlocked.

So altering the above script,

```
my $cmd = "dbus-monitor --session \"type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member='ActiveChanged'\"";

open (IN, "$cmd |");

while (<IN>) {
    if (m/^\s+boolean false/) {
        exec('/path/to/your/script');
    } 
}
```

should do it.

Comment: Here's a variant that works for Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3. It's packaged as a somewhat robust script so that you can reuse it and hopefully build automations on it, like `systemd` services that react to unlock: https://github.com/gogama/lockheed

Answer (score 4):

Building on the bash shell script Michael wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member='ActiveChanged'" | while read line ; do 
    if [ x"$(echo "$line" | grep 'boolean true')" != x ] ; then 
        # runs once when screensaver comes on...
    fi
    if [ x"$(echo "$line" | grep 'boolean false')" != x ] ; then 
        # runs once when screensaver goes off...
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing it in bash to share the same external script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member='ActiveChanged'" | while read line ; do 
        if [ x"$(echo "$line" | grep 'boolean false')" != x ] ; then 
               # do whatever you want here
        fi
done
```